# Uniformization of Riemann surfaces with cone singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a Riemann surface (not necessarily compact), and $x_1, \cdots, x_k$ a set of points on $\Sigma$. Let $n_1, \cdots, n_k$ be a sequence of integers, each of which is $\geq 2$, and such that  $\chi(\Sigma)+\sum_i(n_i-1)<0$. Then the  uniformization theorem (due to McOwen, Troyanov, Hitchin)[edit: apparently the correct attribution is to E. Picard; see comment below] says that there is a unique singular hyperbolic structure on $\Sigma$, where there are conical singularities at $x_i$ with angle $2\pi n_i$, for each $i$. This uniformization corresponds to a representation

$$\rho: \pi_1(\Sigma)\rightarrow PSL_2(\mathbb{R});$$

note that such a representation does not lie in the Teichmüller component of the $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$-character variety of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$, as this would correspond to the smooth hyperbolic metric on $\Sigma$. For a reference, see the chapter by Goldman in  [Problems on Mapping Class Groups and Related Topics](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Efarb/papers/mcgbook.pdf) (page 218), though if there is any error in the above it is due to me.

**Question**: can we describe the Higgs bundle corresponding to $\rho$ under the Simpson correspondence explicitly?

In the case of a smooth metric, the description is as follows.  We take a compactification $\bar{\Sigma}$ of $\Sigma$ by adding points $q_1, \cdots q_s$. Then we have the divisor $D=q_1+\cdots q_s$, the Higgs bundle has the form $L\oplus L^{-1}$ where $L$ is a line bundle with $L^{\otimes 2}\simeq \Omega^1(D)$, and the Higgs field is the tautological isomorphism $\theta: L\rightarrow  L^{-1}\otimes \Omega^1(D)$. In the case of conical singularities at the $x_i$'s it seems to me that the Higgs field must have zeroes at $x_i$ with multiplicity $n_i-1$. I would be happy to understand the case of a single cone singularity with cone angle $4\pi$, for example.

Such a description must be known to Hitchin (if it exists), but looking at [Hitchin's paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59) I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for.

Comment: Just a historical remark: the uniformization theorem you refer to is due to E. Picard and (in modern terminology) to M. Heins, (1962) MR0143901.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the remark! I edited the question accordingly.